# Laplace transform and differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Given

$\frac {d^2y(t)}{dt^2} + a\frac {dy(t)}{dt} = x(t) + by(t)$

Find:

a) $ H(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}$

b) ROC of the stable function and the correspond h(t) and determine if the stable system is causal when a=1, b=2

3. The attempt at a solution

$[s^2 + as - b] Y(s) = X(s)$

$H(s) = \frac{1}{s^2+as-b}$

Then I used 
$ \frac{-a + \sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2}$ to find s but when I use the values given it gives 0. I'm not sure if that means that the system is stable.

Answer (score 0):

Given your differential equation and assuming zero initial conditions for the transfer function, we obtain 
$$
s^2Y(s)+asY(s)-bY(s) = X(s)\Rightarrow H(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)} = \frac{1}{s^2+as-b}
$$
as you have found correctly. Now, we need to determine $h(t)$. We can use the inverse Mellin transform when $a=1$ and $b=2$ where the poles are then $s=1,-2$ 
\begin{align}
h(t) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{e^{st}}{s^2+s-2}ds\\
&= \sum\text{Res}\\
&= \lim_{s\to-2}(s+2)\frac{e^{st}}{s^2+s-2}+\lim_{s\to1}(s-1)\frac{e^{st}}{s^2+s-2}\\
&= \frac{e^t-e^{-2t}}{3}
\end{align}
The ROC for $e^{-2t-st}$ is then $\text{Re}(s)>-2$, and for $e^{t-st}$, $\text{Re}(s)>1$; therefore, $\text{Re}(s)>1$. The system is stable if all poles in the $s$-plane have negative real parts. Since the poles are $s=1,-2$, not all the poles are on the left hand side for $a=1$ and $b=2$.